# HTML number input: how to allow decimal numbers with step=1

Tags: html, input

For a number input, is there a way to have `step=1` yet allow the user to enter decimal numbers?

The reason is I want the arrows on the input box to increase/decrease the value by 1, but allow the user to enter decimals if they want to be more specific.

At the moment I have:

```
<input type="number" name="price" placeholder="£" step="1" id="id_price">
```

The arrows work as intended, but I get a validation error if 2.99 is entered, for example. Removing the step allows decimals to be entered, but the arrows now only increase/decrease by 0.01.

I am leaning towards a Javascript solution, but I was just wondering what the best solution was. Is there another option or an existing library?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`<input type="number" step="any">`  step any allow user to enter decimal too and increase by 1.

Comment: Interesting! Seems to work so far. Is this a reliable cross-browser solution?

Comment: Please add snippet to support your answer

Comment: The only downside I can see is that it the number of decimal places isn't restricted to 2, so they can enter any bizarre number for the price client side. It can be handled server side, sure. It's a trade off I guess...

Comment: In the absence of any obvious solution as simple as this I will accept. In the end I used Javascript to prevent more than 2 decimal places being entered.