# HTML Input allow decimal value but still increment by whole numbers

Tags: html, input, numbers

```
<input type="number" placeholder="Can be a value like 4.23" step="0.01">
```

This accepts decimal numbers, but makes the + / - controls increment by 0.01... not very user friendly. I thought perhaps something like this might work...

```
<input type="number" placeholder="Doesn't allow a value like 4.23" step="1.00">
```

However my browser (Chrome 85) just rounds this back to 1 and rejects `4.23` as invalid.

Some have suggested that using `any` is the solution... I disagree as I want the field to only allow a maximum of 2 decimal places.

```
<input type="number" placeholder="Allows 4.2333333333333" step="any">
```

It seems to me that the increase/decrease step function should not be coupled with the validity of the number, it should just change the way that the + and - buttons work.

I searched around and found [others](https://community.appsheet.com/t/number-decimal-column-step-size-should-not-determine-validity/19924) asking the same question, but I haven't found a resolution.

Comment: maybe you're looking for `step="any"` - http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/input.number.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML number input: how to allow decimal numbers with step=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60151907/html-number-input-how-to-allow-decimal-numbers-with-step-1)

Comment: Not really, it seems a workaround. I want the field to continue to validate only with two decimal places...